# How to handle TimeoutException in selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

First of all, I created several functions to use them instead of default "find_element_by_..." and login() function to create "browser". This is how I use it:

```
def login():
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        return browser

def find_element_by_id_u(browser, element):
    try:
        obj = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id(element)
            )
        return obj
#########
driver = login()
find_element_by_link_text_u(driver, 'the_id')
```

Now I use such tests through jenkins(and launch them on a virtual machine). And in case I got TimeoutException, browser session will not be killed, and I have to manually go to VM and kill the process of Firefox. And jenkins will not stop it's job while web browser process is active.

So I faced the problem and I expect it may be resoved due to exceptions handling.
I tryed to add this to my custom functions, but it's not clear where exactly exception was occured. Even if I got line number, it takes me to my custom function, but not the place where is was called:

```
def find_element_by_id_u(browser, element):
    try:
        obj = WebDriverWait(browser, 1).until(
            lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id(element)
            )
        return obj
    except TimeoutException, err:
        print "Timeout Exception for element '{elem}' using find_element_by_id\n".format(elem = element)
        print traceback.format_exc()
        browser.close()
        sys.exit(1)
#########
driver = login()
driver .get(host)
find_element_by_id_u('jj_username').send_keys('login' + Keys.TAB + 'passwd' + Keys.RETURN)
```

This will print for me the line number of string "lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id(element)" and it's useles for debugging. In my case I have near 3000 rows, so I need a propper line number.

Can you please share your expirience with me.

PS: I divided my program for few scripts, one of them contains only selenium part, that's why I need login() function, to call it from another script and use returned object in it.

Comment: Actually I have some resolution. try: <all selenium code here> except TimeoutException: <print line, url> finally: <browser.close()>   But it seems not the best solution as for me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, spending some time in my mind, I've found a proper solution.

```
def login():
        browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        return browser

def find_element_by_id_u(browser, element):
    try:
        obj = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            lambda browser : browser.find_element_by_id(element)
            )
        return obj
#########
try:
  driver = login()
  find_element_by_id_u(driver, 'the_id')
except TimeoutException:
  print traceback.format_exc()
  browser.close()
  sys.exit(1)
```

It was so obvious, that I missed it :(

Comment: btw, I solved an issue with annoying(browser, ...) while call functions. Created global var for browser and due to this I am able to use it through all the script without putting it into function call.

Comment: What do you have to import?